# Checking for URL.$valid (if then) inside inside AngularJS ng-click. How?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, ternary-operator, angularjs-ng-click

I am making a URL list inside an angular App, Most of the URLs all lead to **`https://`**`example.io`... However a select few have URLs such as **`https://`**`example.io`. I don't want to specify the URL inside every object... I just want to validate the URL then either open the website with `http://` or `https://` depending on what's valid.

I'm using ng-click and binding it to a window open with the url along w/ image nested.

> Index.html

```
    <head>
    <script src="js/shared/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/row.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-app="MainApp">
      <div ng-controller="Main" ng-cloak>
        <div id="RowDiv">
          <button style="visibility: hidden; width: 25px;"></button>
          <a ng-repeat="r1 in r1s" ng-click="openurl(r1.url.$valid==true?r1.url:'https://' + r1.name + '.io')"  ng-cloak>
            <img ng-src="img/{{r1.name}}.png" height="40px">
            </a>
            <button style="visibility: hidden; width: 25px;"></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="LftBtn" style="z-index: 1000;" >
        <i id="L-Arrow"></i>
    </button>

    <button id="RgtBtn" style="z-index: 1000;" >
        <i id="R-Arrow"></i>
    </button>

    <script src="js/protractor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/row.js"></script>
    </body>
```

> protractor.js

```
    var app = angular.module("MainApp", []);

    // - - app controllers - - \\

    app.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.r1s = [
        {name: 'Surviv', url: 'https://google.com'},
        //Just a test, urls will be changed later
        {name: 'Zombsroyale'},
        {name: 'Bruh'},
        {name: 'Krunker'},
        {name: 'Shellshock'},
        {name: 'Diep'},
        {name: 'Tanked'},
        {name: 'Gats'},
        {name: 'Warbot'},
        {name: 'Counterstroke'}
      ];
      $scope.openurl = function(url){
        if(window.parent == window.top) {
          //If outside
          window.open(url, "_blank"});
        } else {
          //If inside
          window.open(url, '_parent');
        }
      };
    }]);
```

The main thing here is the `url` validation,
and the <kbd>ng-click</kbd>`="openurl(r1.url.$valid == true ? 'http://' + r1.name '.io' : 'https://' + r1.name + '.io')"`

I am clueless as to why this isn't working, it will open the popup, but it will ignore the ternary & $valid parameters completely...
I've tried swapping the
- `.$valid==true`
w/
- `.$valid==false`
but I get the same result! Why's this not working?

A working example on plunkr, jsfiddle, or codepen, etc would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long hours of searching...
I stumbled upon [This](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-validate-for-a-URL-in-JavaScript) Website...
After implementation the code would look like this:

> Index.html changes

<strike>`ng-click="openurl(r1.url.$valid==true?r1.url:'https://' + r1.name + '.io')"`</strike>
to
`ng-click="is_url(r1.name+'.io')"`

> protractor.js changes/ additions

<strike>`{name: 'Surviv', url: 'https://google.com'},`</strike>
to
`{name: 'Surviv'},`

inside the main controller:
add:

```
$scope.is_url = function(str) {
        regexp =  /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
        if (regexp.test('https://' + str))
        {
            chrome.windows.create({url: 'https://' + str, type: "popup"});
        }
        else
        {
            chrome.windows.create({url: 'http://' + str, type: "popup"});
        }
};
```

I used `window.open` in the previous example/use
I have since changed it to `chrome.windows.create`
to use this with `window.open` -
change `{url: 'http://' + str, type: "popup"}` Or `{url: 'https://' + str, type: "popup"}`

to: `'http://' + str, "_blank"` Or `'https://' + str, "_blank"`.

This took way too many hours of googling... Hopefully everyone else who ever runs in to this issue will now find an easier method of use...